# How does reduced redundancy storage (RRS) fit in S3 storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is a highy theoretical question as I am trying to get familiarized with S3 storage classes. [The storage classes page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/?nc=sn&loc=3) in AWS docs does not mention RRS at all. RRS has its [own page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/reduced-redundancy/) in AWS docs. The [S3 lifecycle transitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html) doc makes it even more confusing with a diagram that shows standard storage class and reduced redundancy in the same block. see below
[image]

AWS console does give an option to choose RRS but says that it is not recommended as Standard is more cost effective. shouldn't reduced redundancy result in reduced cost?

[image]

I am having trouble understanding how RRS fits in with S3 storage classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It usually doesn't fit.  Not any more.

Reduced Redundancy (RRS) is a legacy storage class.  It is the oldest storage class (besides `STANDARD`) and was originally [announced back in 2010](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/05/19/announcing-amazon-s3-reduced-redundancy-storage/).

It stored objects with less physical redundancy (fewer device failures inside S3 were necessary before the object was lost completely) and subsequently the cost was indeed lower than Standard *at the time.*

But then something paradoxical occurred: the cost of Standard was reduced significantly... so significantly, in fact, that the price of Standard was reduced to below the cost of RRS in most -- but not all -- regions.  In São Paulo, for example, Standard is $0.0405/GB and RRS is $0.0326/GB.  In most regions, though, RRS is no longer cost effective.

Unofficially, I've heard it said that the underlying architectures of Standard and RRS are actually more different than we might imagine, and internal innovation drove down the cost of Standard but not that of RRS because of these differences.  There is not, as far as I am aware, an official explanation of the counter-intuitive pricing discrepancy.

The other storage classes all came later.  [The `GLACIER` storage class dates back to 2012](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/).

More recently, Standard/IA, then one-zone IA, and finally Deep Archive were released... and Intelligent Tiering a real storage class.